# Find and Replace the Opening Curly Bracket of Every Method in Xcode Project

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm changing my coding style a bit, and would like to change a formatting pattern I used throughout a large project.

Within the implementation of a given method, I place an opening curly brace `{` one space after the last character in the method name. I'd like to find and replace each instance of this pattern with the opening brace on a new line--i.e.

```
- (void)myMethod:(id)aParameter 
{
    // Code
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use a code formatter, such as [uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net). Of course, that will be a much larger change than your proposal. Very nice to have a program do the work for you in the long term.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I need some time to study this...not tonight =p)

Comment: @justin : I wonder which is better to have... { in same line or in new line?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya well, it's just preference after all. in *most* places, i put my curly brackets on the same line. for objc method definitions, i put them on a *new line* (as seen in the OP).